# Pass command line arguments to python script that is called through unix executable

Tags: python, bash

I have a file named "uscf" in /usr/local/bin:

```
#! /bin/sh
python3 ~/Desktop/path/to/uscf.py
```

I have already `chmod +x` this file so that I can run it from my terminal with the command "`uscf`". How can I run this with command line arguments so that the arguments are accessible through `sys.argv` in uscf.py?

EDIT: Added below example for clarification:

The uscf.py file:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
print(sys.argv)
```

Running it from the command line:

```
Abraham$ uscf these are arguments
```

Expected output:

```
these are arguments
```

Comment: did you mean to say that you want to take `input` from the python script, here `uscf.py` ?

Comment: Are you talking about argparse? https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: No, I want to run the unix executable through the command line and give it some arguments

Comment: I would make it `#!/usr/bin/python` and have `setup.py` have scripts section to call your python executable with argparse or argv

Comment: See jordanm's answer, it is what I was looking for.

I also added an edit for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sh the "$@" variable contains all the positional arguments passed to the script. You can use that to pass it to your python script:

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 $HOME/Desktop/path/to/uscf.py "$@"
```

Comment: You cannot use `~` for `$HOME` in `sh` scripts. See also [Difference between sh and bash](/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)